# Two separate english strings.xml android

Tags: android, localization

I am developing my app to incorporate two english language strings. Let's say one for British English other for US English.
Please mind that I want to have **same language but two `strings.xml` files**.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit : How can I change app language programmatically with two english files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. From [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources):

> The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code, optionally followed by a two letter [ISO 3166-1-alpha-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/en/prods-services/iso3166ma/02iso-3166-code-lists/list-en1.html) region code (preceded by lowercase "r")

For example, for British English strings, you should use `res/values-en-rGB`

**Edit**: To change the language programatically, you can use:

```
locale = new Locale(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.UK);
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) for more details

Please note that since both languages are English, you would only update the second parameter of the `Locale()` constructor based on user selection

Comment: Can you also tell how do I change language programmatically then ?

Comment: I know how to do this with two different language .... I am asking how to change it with different region but same language.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 values folder like below and have 2 separate strings.xml in it.

values-en-rGB (For UK English)
values-en-rUS (For US English)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

values
  - strings.xml

values-en-rGB
  - strings.xml

Basically the format goes like this.
values-(language_code)-r(region_name)