# Two locale files for a same Language. Is it possible?

Tags: android, locale

I am developing an android app in which i am trying to support different dialects of the same language given by two different clients. For Chinese currently there are multiple locales available. But for Spanish, We can keep the translation of any one of the above files in **strings-es.xml**. Is it possible two keep the two files and use the one based on the requirement?

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/42464716/7846071

Comment: @NensiKasundra Thank you. But unfortunately, Both the clients are from same region and same country. Only the way of translation they required is different.

Comment: You can have 2 values folder like below and have 2 separate strings.xml in it.


values-en-rGB (For UK English)
values-en-rUS (For US English)